# Nested Subqueries with Group By

Tags: sql

Having trouble with this one. Getting syntax error at the arrow. I'm using subqueries on purpose. I'm wondering if it's possible to mix 'where' and 'having'?

```
;with books_not_ordered as
(
  select BK.book_id
  from bkinfo.books BK
  where BK.book_id not in
  (
    select OD.book_id
    from bkorders.order_details OD
  )  
)
select AU.author_id, AU.author_name_last
from bkinfo.authors AU
where exists
(
  select BAU.author_id, count(*) as NumBooks
  from bkinfo.book_authors BAU  
  group by BAU.author_id
  having count(*) > 1
  ==>where AU.author_id = BAU.author_id
  and
  BAU.book_id in
  (
    select BK.book_id
    from bkinfo.books BK
    where BK.book_id in
    (
      select cte.book_id
      from books_not_ordered cte
    )    
  )
)   
;
go
```

Answer (score 2):

The where clause should come before your group by and having

```
select BAU.author_id, count(*) as NumBooks
  from bkinfo.book_authors BAU  
  where AU.author_id = BAU.author_id
  group by BAU.author_id
  having count(*) > 1
```

Comment: But then I get a HAVING error because BAU.book_id isn't in the Group By. But If I put it in the Group By, I'm grouping wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are trying to get "The authors of the books that are not in `order_details` table, but who have written more than one book". The following query should work.

```
SELECT AU.author_id, AU.author_name_last
FROM bkinfo.books BK
    JOIN bkinfo.book_authors BAU ON BAU.author_id = BK.author_id
    JOIN bkinfo.authors AU ON BAU.author_id = AU.author_id
    LEFT OUTER JOIN bkorders.order_details OD ON BK.book_id = OD.book_id
WHERE OD.book_id IS NULL
GROUP BY AU.author_id, AU.author_name_last
HAVING COUNT(BK.Book_id) > 1
```

Comment: You have the objective exactly right! However, I need to use subqueries unfortunately.